# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'iglob'

Tags: python, django

Strange error. I'm just trying to get the models right in my DB, but fail at the very first. Here is my glob.models:

```
from django.db import models

class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.status_name
```

When I try to run syncd, I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'iglob'

Comment: It might be caused by some other things you installed/implemented. I don't find anything suspicious for your model. Can you post the full backtrace?

Comment: What does your setting.py look like? This could be a misconfiguration in there. Make sure you obscure any passwords before posting.

Comment: well, none of that really helped me. I ended up recreating the application and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your models are in `glob.models` - I assume the app name is `glob`. Is it possible that you may have made a typo somewhere - `iglob` instead of `glob`?

The code you pasted has no mention of the word `iglob`. I suggest you do a project wide search for `iglob` and see if it's meant to be `glob`.

Comment: well, none of that really helped me. I ended up recreating the application and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your variable name is almost the same as the imported module name. You can try to use import some_module as name to avoid this issue.